# What format should I use for my android app icon?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, icons

I am developing an android app and I have a doubt, which format is better for the app icon ? Should I use PNG or SVG (vector) format? What size should I use?
P.s. Putting the app icon in png, every time a notification of my app arrives, the notification menu has lag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use both of them but i think that SVG is better than PNG
because when you using SVG format your image quality does not decrease
and size of app icon is 512*512

Comment: thank you, but if I use an SVG, the app icon in the notification appears gray, like a gray square, it's like it doesn't take the app icon

Comment: we have an attribute in notification section that is  setSmallIcon() and you can use this to set notification icon

Answer (score 1):

I normally use PNG for those images. Although, there is no "better" format, they are both good in their own ways.